# Variables as 'literals'

Tags: javascript

I am wondering whether I can use variables that I pass to a function as arguments as "literals" (I don't know a better way to describe the problem, perhaps the example will clear things up):

```
banana = yellow;
minion = cute;

function ex(banana, minion) {
    banana.minion;
}

// What I want is: yellow.cute
```

**Edit**
I think I might not have been asking exactly what I meant. I'm sorry for that. Here's the actual code that might clarify things.

```
function ex(banana, minion){
    createjs.Tween.get(banana, {override: true}).to({banana: minion}, -(value + -banana.minion) * speed, createjs.Ease.ease);
console.log(banana); // returns 'yellow'
console.log(minion); // returns 'cute'
console.log(banana.minion); // returns 'undefined'
console.log(banana[minion]); // returns 'undefined' too
}
```

So I want to pass whatever I define as `banana` or `minion` to be 'literal', so that it will read `createjs.Tween.get(yellow, {override: true}).to({yellow: cute}, -(value + -yellow.cute) * speed, createjs.Ease.ease);`

Comment: WHat does your function do ? does it return anything ?

Comment: Are you looking to return this as a string variable?

Comment: So you just want to call `banana(minion)` inside your `ex`function ...?

Comment: Please see updated question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the name as a string and use the array syntax to access the property.

```
function ex(banana, minion) {
  return banana[minion];
}
```

If you want the left hand side of an object to be a string as well (e.g. `banana`, you could use `eval(banana)[minion]` but that might raise a few eyebrows at a code review.  Note that this works for both properties and methods e.g. `eval(banana)[minion]()`, though I'd step back a bit and ask why you need to do this kind of moderately bonkers stuff :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clearer. `minion` is supposed to reference to a method. So the function will pass whatever name I pass to `minion` as the method for `banana`. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @AKG: Method or property, it doesn't matter. You can use the same idea for methods.

Comment: Please see updated question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

ex

```
 banana[minion];
```